# Html to Pdf with german alphabet

Tags: java, html-to-pdf, flying-saucer, openhtmltopdf

I'm using [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) to transform html to pdf. Currently I'm getting an exception if the html contains german characters, like for example ä,ö,ü.

```
  PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
  builder.useFastMode();
  builder.withHtmlContent(html,"file://localhost/");
  builder.toStream(out);
  builder.run();
```

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 31; The
>   entity "auml" was referenced, but not declared.

Here my html:

```
<html>
   <head>      
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        k&auml;se
    </body>
</html>
```

The exported word is "käse" (cheese).

---

UPDATE

I have tried with an entity resolver, in this way:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder=null;
    try{
      builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();

      ByteArrayInputStream input=new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      builder.setEntityResolver(FSEntityResolver.instance());
      org.w3c.dom.Document doc=builder.parse(input);


    }catch(Exception e){
      logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

but I'm still getting the same exception at "parse".

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your HTML-Document where you want to create the PDF?

Comment: Yes, I have added my html

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you either need to provide [DTD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp) or replace the entity name `auml` with its corresponding hex or decimal value, i.e. `&#xE4;` or `&#228;` respectively. See [A.2. Entity Sets](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#h-A2) and [HTML 4 Entity Names](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp).

The html content would look like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
        <!ENTITY auml "&#228;">
]>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        k&auml;se
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can run through the html string and replace the entity names with their corresponding dec/hex values, which should be fine, or just prepend the DTD to your html string before passing it to the pdf builder.

---

**Update**

You might want to give the [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library a try. It It parses and provides you with a `org.w3c.dom.Document`, e.g.

```java
Document jsoupDoc = Jsoup.parse(html); // org.jsoup.nodes.Document
W3CDom w3cDom = new W3CDom(); // org.jsoup.helper.W3CDom
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = w3cDom.fromJsoup(jsoupDoc);
```

You can then pass the `w3cDoc` to the pdf builder like so

```java
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.withW3cDocument(w3cDoc, "file://localhost/");
```

Comment: Your answer goes in the right direction, thx. I'm pretty sure I can do it programmatically, instead of declaring the DTD in the html. I have tried using an entity resolver (I have updated my question), still not working, but I think I'm closer...

Comment: @Zardo the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` you are using requires a well defined document, which is not the case with the html file you provided. I updated my answer. `jsoup` would help you with the html parsing part, so that you don't have to touch your existing html files.